# rsplit() is not working to split columns using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split, strsplit

Original df

```
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.DataFrame({
    'Ref':['CU12','SE00', 'RLA1234', 'RLA456', 'LU00', 'RLA1234MA12','RLA1234MA13', 'CU00','LU00']
} )

    Ref
0   CU12
1   SE00
2   RLA1234
3   12345
4   RLA456
5   LU00
6   RLA1234MA12
7   RLA1234MA13
8   CU00
9   LU00
```

Requirement:
I need to split the strings and numbers using regex and rsplit().
I have 3 types of values here

1. string + numbers
2. numbers
3. string + numbers +string+ numbers.
   I need to rsplit() and get only the numbers from right and then the rest of the string
   So,

CU12         should give CU and 12 ,
RLA1234MA12  should give RLA1234MA and 12 ,
12345        should give 12345.

split() works fine and splits the columns correctly, but when it comes to rsplit()
my regex fails to produce desired columns. i did read the documentation for split() and rsplit().
Here what i have tried.
My  df looks like this

```
result = df['Ref'].str.split('([A-Za-z]*)(\d*)', expand=True)
```

This gives me

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0       CU  12                  None    None    None
1       SE  00                  None    None    None
2       RLA 1234                    None    None    None
3           12345                   None    None    None
4       RLA 456                 None    None    None
5       LU  00                  None    None    None
6       RLA 1234        MA  12              
7       RLA 1234        MA  13              
8       CU  00                  None    None    None
9       LU  00                  None    None    None
```

i need to get only 2 columns in my result so that i can do something like this

```
result = result.loc[:,[1,2]]
result.rename(columns={1:'x', 2:'y'}, inplace=True)
print(result)


x   y
0   CU  12
1   SE  00
2   RLA 1234
3       12345
4   RLA 456
5   LU  00
6   RLA1234MA   12
7   RLA1234MA   13
8   CU  00
9   LU  00
```

But when i use rsplit() my columns do not split as they do in split().

The only option for me now is to use apply on my column and write a custom function which will traverse the string from the end and slices it as soon as it finds a character.
Is there a way using rsplit().
Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: There is a clear bug in the Pandas documentation. `rsplit` does NOT support regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) along with the given `regex` pattern having named capturing groups:

```
result = df['Ref'].str.extract(r'(?P<x>\w*?)(?P<y>\d*)$')
```

OR, It is also possible to use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True`:

```
result = df['Ref'].str.split(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d+$)', expand=True)
```

Result:

```
# print(result)

           x      y
0         CU     12
1         SE     00
2        RLA   1234
3             12345
4        RLA    456
5         LU     00
6  RLA1234MA     12
7  RLA1234MA     13
8         CU     00
9         LU     00
```

Test the `regex` pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/77xhQn/3).

Comment: Your first solution works, but the `df['Ref'].str.split(r'(?<=\D)(?=\d+$)', expand=True)` one is not handling `12345` row correctly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for pointing out I guess `12345` appearing in first column, I will try to correct it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Any suggestion if its even possible to use `regex` here to use  `Series.str.split` on the column?

Comment: I'd use `df['Ref'].str.split(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d+$)', expand=True)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you explain little more why `\D` is not working here? As `\D` can match any character that's not in `[0-9]`.

Comment: `(?<=\D)` requires a non-digit char immediately on the left of the current location. `(?:(?<=\D)|^)` would work (same + start of string location allowed). But `(?<!\d)` is simpler/shorter.

Comment: Oh, i understand the mistake, i've forget about `^`, thanks for taking time out for explaining..